# React said: "Can not find namespace..." in creation of Context

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context

I create a Context in React.js with TypeScript but this error had occurred:
*Cannot find namespace 'JobContext'.ts(2503)*

```
import React, { createContext, useState }       from 'react';

export const JobContext = createContext<any>({});

const JobContextProvider = ({ children }) => {

    const [data, setData] = useState<any>();

    const updatingState = (newData) => setData({ ...data, ...newData });

    return (
        <JobContext.Provider value={{data, updatingState}}>
            {children}
        </JobContext.Provider>
    );

};

export default JobContextProvider;
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Because as React has said, the extension of your file is `.ts`, which should be  `.tsx`.

Comment: Hours and hours again to find this solution Many thanks

Comment: OH MY GOD. this save me.. really save me